# Display console in uiview, uitextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

Is it possible to display my console output (in xcode) to iphone ?
For example: if in my code I write NSLog(@"hello\n"); I will be able to see it in the device
in the same way I see it in console. (and of-course next time next nslog should not erase the previous one ) some sort of redirect the console.

Comment: Create a file that will keep on appending your logs. Show this file in textview.

Comment: There are various answers depending on what you really need. Do you just want to see the console output of a device? Meaning, is it ok to see the console within xcode? Or do you really need to see that output within the same app?

Comment: In case that my program running for long time i don't want to wait until the end i want it to happen at the same time. will i need to be root to open a file ?

Comment: I want to see the output of my exact application.

Comment: Then I suggest you do what @AnoopVaidya suggested already. AFAIK the console is not accessible within the app's sandbox and I am not aware of any 'legal' API that could provide you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this macro

```
 #define  YourLog(PR)               {NSLog(@"%@",PR); yourTextFld.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",yourTextFld.text,PR] ; }
```

Remember you have to change  with your txt field name if this macro dosent work use this idea with some tweaks wrote in hurry

Comment: Modify it according to your usage.

Comment: Was thinking about where this macro could fail but could not come up with a good example, but usually they allways do somewhere. i would rather stick with a static function instead, much safer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file that will keep on appending your logs.

Show this file in textfield or textview.